# General error:1364 :Field 'dis' does not have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, forms

I am getting error 1364. Field 'dis' does not have a default value. I am going well with form and CRUD operation. In saving data in the database through form I got this error. Create form redirects to show view. I got this error when I click on the submit button of my form. I check my database data is not stored there.

Error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'dis' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into 
`students` (`full_name`, `dob`, `gender`, `cnic`, `marital_Status`, `nationality`, `religion`, 
`domicile`, `province`, `father_name`, `father_cnic`, `father_profession`, `guardian_name`, 
`guardian_cnic`, `email`, `address`, `tel_landline`, `tel_office`, `cell1`, `cell2`, 
`matric_obtained_marks`, `matric_total_marks`, `matric_marksheet_image`, `fsc_obtained_marks`, 
`fsc_total_marks`, `fsc_marksheet_image`, `nmdcat_obtained_marks`, `nmdcat_total_marks`, 
 `nmdcat_result_image`, `updated_at`,
```

Here is my controller

```
class StudentsController extends Controller 
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function index()
 {
     return view ('index');
 }

 /**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function create()
 {
     return view('create');
 }

 /**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $student= new student;
  $student->full_name=$request->full_name;
  $student->dob=$request->dob;
  $student->gender=$request->dis;
  $student->cnic=$request->cnic;
  $student->marital_Status=$request->marital_status;
  $student->nationality=$request->nationality;
  $student->religion=$request->religion;
  $student->domicile=$request->domicile;
  $student->province=$request->province;
  $student->father_name=$request->father_name;
  $student->father_cnic=$request->father_cnic;
  $student->father_profession=$request->father_profession;
  $student->guardian_name=$request->guardian_name;
  $student->guardian_cnic=$request->guardian_cnic;
  $student->email=$request->email;
  $student->address=$request->address;
  $student->tel_landline=$request->tel_lanline;
  $student->tel_office=$request->tel_office;
  $student->cell1=$request->cell1;
  $student->cell2=$request->cell2;
  $student->matric_obtained_marks=$request->matric_obtained_marks;
  $student->matric_total_marks=$request->matric_total_marks;
  $student->matric_marksheet_image=$request->matric_marksheet_image;
  $student->fsc_obtained_marks=$request->fsc_obtained_marks;
  $student->fsc_total_marks=$request->fsc_total_marks;
  $student->fsc_marksheet_image=$request->fsc_marksheet_image;
  $student->nmdcat_obtained_marks=$request->nmdcat_obtained_marks;
  $student->nmdcat_total_marks=$request->nmdcat_total_marks;
  $student->nmdcat_result_image=$request->nmdcat_result_image;
  $student->save();

  return redirect('/show');

}
```

Here is my form

```
                <form action="/students" method="post">
      {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name of applicant:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="full_name" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label for="example-date-input" class="col-6 col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2001-05-19" id="example-date-input" name="dob" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="gen">
                     <label for="example-date-input" class="col-3 col-form-label" id="gender">Gender:</label>
                     <div class="col-9" id="gnd">
                      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="inlineRadio1" value="male"> Male
                        </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline" id="fma">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="inlineRadio2" value="female"> Female
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4" id="dis">
                      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="col-2 col-form-label">Disability:</label>
                        <div class="col-7">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="dis" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">CNIC:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="cnic" placeholder="Enter your CNIC" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="example-date-input" class="col-6 col-form-label">Marital Status:</label>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="marital_status">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5" id="nat">
                  <label for="example-date-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Nationality:</label>
                        <div class="col-7">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nationality" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5" id="rel">
                  <label for="example-date-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Religion:</label>
                        <div class="col-7">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="religion" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="example-date-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Domicile:</label>
                    <div class="col-7">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="domicile" placeholder="Your domicile" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="dom">
                    <label for="example-date-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Province:</label>
                    <div class="col-7">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="province" placeholder="Your province" required>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Father Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="father_name" placeholder="Enter your father name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Father CNIC:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="father_cnic" placeholder="Enter father CNIC" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Father Profession:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="father_profession" placeholder="Enter father profession" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Guardian Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="guardian_name" placeholder="Enter your guardian name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Guardian CNIC:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="guardian_cnic" placeholder="Enter guardian CNIC" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-9">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Permanent and Mailing Address:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" name="address" placeholder="Enter your address" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Tel (Landline):</label>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel_landline" placeholder="Landline">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8" id="tel1">
                        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Tel (Office):</label>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel_office" placeholder="Office">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Cell 1:</label>
                        <div class="col-7">
                            <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="cell1" placeholder="0***-*******" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-7" id="cell2">
                        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-4 col-form-label">Cell 2:</label>
                        <div class="col-7">
                            <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="cell2" placeholder="0***-*******" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label id="mat">Matric/O Level Marks:</label>
                <div class="form-row" id="mar">
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Obtained Marks:</label>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="matric_obtained_marks" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8" id="tom">
                        <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Total Marks:</label>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" max="1100" name="matric_total_marks" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label id="mat">Matric/O Level Marksheet:</label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-9">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04" name="matric_marksheet_image" >
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="upl">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <small id="mat" class="form-text text-muted">Upload scanned picture of your Matric/O Level marksheet</small>
                <br>
                <label id="mat">FSc/A-Level Marks:</label>
                <div class="form-row" id="mar">
                    <br>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                      <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Obtained Marks:</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="fsc_obtained_marks" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8" id="tom">
                      <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Total Marks:</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" max="1100" name="fsc_total_marks" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label id="mat">FSc/A-Level Marksheet:</label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-9">
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04" name="fsc_marksheet_image" >
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Choose file</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="upl">Upload</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <small id="mat" class="form-text text-muted">Upload scanned picture of your FSc/A-Level marksheet</small>
                <br>
                <label id="mat">NMDCAT Marks:</label>
                <div class="form-row" id="mar">
                    <br>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                      <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Obtained Marks:</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="nmdcat_obtained_marks" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8" id="tom">
                      <label for="example-date-input" class="col-5 col-form-label">Total Marks:</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="number" name="nmdcat_total_marks" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label id="mat">NMDCAT Result:</label>
                <div class="input-group col-md-9">
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04" name="nmdcat_result_image" >Choose file</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="upl">Upload</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <small id="mat" class="form-text text-muted">Upload scanned picture of your NMDCAT result</small>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-2" id="sig" align="center" center>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        @endsection
```

Here is my migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('full_name');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->text('gender');
        $table->text('dis');
        $table->biginteger('cnic');
        $table->text('marital_status');
        $table->text('nationality');
        $table->text('religion');
        $table->text('domicile');
        $table->text('province');
        $table->text('father_name');
        $table->biginteger('father_cnic');
        $table->text('father_profession');
        $table->text('guardian_name');
        $table->biginteger('guardian_cnic');
        $table->text('email');
        $table->text('address');
        $table->biginteger('tel_landline');
        $table->biginteger('tel_office');
        $table->biginteger('cell1');
        $table->biginteger('cell2');
        $table->integer('matric_obtained_marks');
        $table->integer('matric_total_marks');
        $table->binary('matric_marksheet_image');
        $table->integer('fsc_obtained_marks');
        $table->integer('fsc_total_marks');
        $table->binary('fsc_marksheet_image');
        $table->integer('nmdcat_obtained_marks');
        $table->integer('nmdcat_total_marks');
        $table->binary('nmdcat_result_image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: store function dont have $student->dis = $request->dis

Comment: *I am getting error 1364. Field 'dis' does not have a default value.* This means that (1) field `'dis'` does not have default value and at the same time is defined as NOT NULL (2) you try to insert new row using query where `dis` column is not mentioned at all. The most simple solution is to execute according ALTER TABLE and specify default value for this column.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not saving any data to dis field in your database, instead dis input field is saving data to gender field in your database. Do it like this

```
$student->dis=$request->dis;
```

or assign some default value to dis field in your database.

Comment: or add in migrations file. 
$table->text('dis')->nullable();//$table->text('dis')->default('value');

Answer (score 0):

Here in your table dis column is not nullable. so when you save any row this column need to fill. To solve this problem you need to nullable this column or set a default value for this. add a new migration file & make this column nullable or set default value.

```
$table->text('dis')->nullable();
```

or

```
$table->text('dis')->default('your_disere_value');
```

Or save dis column value from blade to controller.

```
$student->dis=$request->dis;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your primary key to NOT NULL like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee_details MODIFY emp_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```